# solving equation with linear span (using row reduction)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, span

We've got the following span:
$$U = Sp\{(2, 5, -4, -10), (1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0,3,5) , (0,2,-4,-8)\}$$

We need to find the values of the number $a$ where the vector $$v = (a, a-6, 4a-3, 6a-1)$$ belongs to $U$.

since $U$ is a span I know that I can use it as linear combination

Let $U = Sp\{u1,u2,u3,u4\}$
$$v = a1u1 + a2u2 + a3u3 + a4u4$$

we can use a matrix now:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&1&0& |& a \\
5&1&0&2&|&a-6\\
-4&1&3&-4&|&4a-3\\
-10&1&5&-8&|&6a-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

do I need to use row reduction now?
also, when I'll get canonical matrix how do I continue from there also?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally was able to solve it after an hour of attemp's using row reduction!

this is my solution:
I used this matrix from the question 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&1&0& |& a \\
5&1&0&2&|&a-6\\
-4&1&3&-4&|&4a-3\\
-10&1&5&-8&|&6a-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and done row reduction until I got
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&1&0& |& a \\
5&1&0&2&|&a-6\\
0&3&5&-4&|&6a-3\\
0&0&0&0&|&2a-10
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which means that $a$ must be equal to 5 in order for it to belong to $U$.

(any additions to this answer will be much appreciated)

Comment: In general, you will want to continue row reducing -- if you do so in this case one more row will disappear and you'll get another condition on $a$.  However it just so happens that the condition is the same: $a=5$, so there is a solution.

Comment: @Bye_World thank you for you answer, just to clarify why would I need to continue row reduction ?

Comment: You row reduced to find a row of all zeroes and then to make the system consistent, your expression on the right had to equal zero as well.  Great.  But if you row reduce this completely, you'll find that $2$ rows become all zero.  So there's a chance that you could get contradictory conditions on $a$ and thus no solution.  In this case, both conditions are $a=5$, so you're fine.  But in general, you'd need to check.